# PHP: Remove Simple Session with Get-Method

Tags: php, session

I want to Remove the Sessions from this php code, actually if someone searches i get this url *search.php?searchquery=test* but if I reload the page, the results are cleaned. how can I remove the Sessions to get the Results still, if someone reloads the page? this are the codes:

search.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<form method="get" action="querygoogle.php">
<label for="searchquery"><span class="caption">Search this site</span> <input type="text" size="20" maxlength="255" title="Enter your keywords and click the search button" name="searchquery" /></label> <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<?php
if(!empty($_SESSION['googleresults']))
{
echo $_SESSION['googleresults'];
unset($_SESSION['googleresults']);
}
?>
```

querygoogle.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$url = 'http://www.example.com';
$handle = fopen($url, 'rb');
$body = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
$body .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);

$json = json_decode($body);

foreach($json->responseData->results as $searchresult)
{
if($searchresult->GsearchResultClass == 'GwebSearch')
{
$formattedresults .= '
<div class="searchresult">
<h3><a href="' . $searchresult->unescapedUrl . '">' . $searchresult->titleNoFormatting . '</a></h3>
<p class="resultdesc">' . $searchresult->content . '</p>
<p class="resulturl">' . $searchresult->visibleUrl . '</p>
</div>';
}
}

$_SESSION['googleresults'] = $formattedresults;
header("Location: search.php?searchquery=" . $_GET['searchquery']);
exit;
?>
```

thank you for your help!!

Answer (score -1):

This is against google's terms of use. [Use google API](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/ajaxsearch/)